# Where clause slows down query

Tags: mysql, database

The query below searches the selections that customer did before and gets the correct results.  Anyway, The query should be as fast as possible. While testing I realized where clause slows down the query. Hoq can we solve this problem?

```
SELECT 
customerselections.customer_id,
customerselections.selectedcompany_id,
companycampaigns.*,
companies.company_logo
FROM  customerselections

INNER JOIN companycampaigns ON companycampaigns.company_id=customerselections.selectedcompany_id  
INNER JOIN companies ON companies.company_id=customerselections.selectedcompany_id

WHERE customerselections.customer_id='$customerid' LIMIT $offset,$limit
```

UPDATE: explain results

customer selections:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows      Extra
 1  SIMPLE  customerselections  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    12799999
```

companycampaigns

```
 id select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
 1  SIMPLE  companycampaigns    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2000000
```

Companies

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  companies   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2039500
```

QUERY EXPLAIN

```
|id|select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys        |           key |   key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |

|1|SIMPLE | customerselections | ref | selectedcompany_id,customer_id | customer_id | 4   | const  |  2   9 |  |

|1|SIMPLE| companycampaigns  | ref  | company_id   | company_id  | 4  | viptrio.customerselections.selectedcompany_id | 1 |  |

|1|SIMPLE| companies  | eq_ref | PRIMARY  | PRIMARY  | 4 | viptrio.customerselections.selectedcompany_id |1 |  |
```

UPDATE

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies` (
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `company_customerid` int(11) default NULL,
  `company_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `company_description` tinytext,
  `company_email` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `company_website` tinytext,
   `company_gsm` tinytext,
  `company_landline` tinytext,
  `company_fax` tinytext,
  `company_address` tinytext,
  `company_contactperson` tinytext,
  `company_businessid` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_cityid` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `company_countrycode` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `company_refnum` tinytext,
  `company_regdate` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `company_logo` tinytext,
  `company_keyword` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`company_id`),
  KEY `company_cityid` (`company_cityid`),
  KEY `company_countrycode` (`company_countrycode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2039501 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companycampaigns` (
`campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`campaign_title` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`campaign_detail` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`campaign_startdate` tinytext,
`campaign_enddate` tinytext,
`published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (`campaign_id`),
KEY `company_id` (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2000001 ;



  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customerselections` (
  `selection_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `selectedcompany_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`selection_id`),
  KEY `selectedcompany_id` (`selectedcompany_id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12800006 ;
```

Comment: is it slow even without where clause?

Comment: @AshReva: a lot faster. With "where clause" it takes around 0,30, without it, the query time is around 0,15

Comment: Try adding the where clause in the first `ON` clause `FROM  customerselections INNER JOIN companycampaigns ON customerselections.customer_id='$customerid' AND companycampaigns.company_id=customerselections.selectedcompany_id  
INNER JOIN companies ON  companies.company_id=customerselections.selectedcompany_id LIMIT $offset,$limit`     Hope this helps..

Comment: Do you really need **all** columns from **all** tables? Is there an index on `customer_id`. Aren't you confusing lazy loading with performance and finally :), can you show us the execution plan?

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers: I don't need all columns. I edited my question. Please see update. I have necessary indexes on necessary columns.

Comment: @mustafa - You could confirm that with posting the execution plan.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers: Please see update.

Comment: @mustafa - Is this the plan for the query you've shown us? It mentions a filesort but there's no order by on your statement.

Comment: @mustafa - Also: try to create a covering index on `customerselections (customerid, selectedcompany_id)`.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers : Yes there was "order by". While testing I removed ORDER BY from the query to see if it has any effect.

Comment: @mustafa - Well, it *has* an effect: it forces MySQL to do an extra pass to do the sorting. Can you post the plan for the *exact* statement you are currently having problems with? And did you try adding the covering index?

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers : I am just reindexing columns. I will  update question  soon.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers; I've updated "EXPLAIN result" for the query in my questions. The table "customerselections" has 12 millions of row. The query time  is around 0.300

Comment: I don't see the covering index even mentioned in the plan. Can you post the DDL of the table? For the record, I assume that the select without any where clause is faster only because **it can start streaming results** sooner but if you would try to get to the last record, you will notice the where clause resultset being much faster.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers: please see update.

Comment: @mustafa - There isn't a **covering index** on customerid and selectedcompany_id. All I can see are **two separate** indexes on those fields. Can you try adding a covering index? *(using SQL Server, the statement would look like this: create index ix_whatever on customerselections (customerid, selectedcompany_id))*

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers: I created covering index. Query time  changes between 0.160 and 0.300. Is this normal with 12.000.000 rows of customerselections?

Comment: @mustafa - It can be explained with current load, time of the day, phase of the moon, ... :). It's not something I would worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (with an index on customer_id):

```
SELECT t1.customer_id, t1.selectedcompany_id,
       cc.*, c.company_logo
FROM   (SELECT customer_id, selectedcompany_id,
        FROM   customerselections 
        WHERE customer_id='$customerid' ) AS t1
INNER JOIN companycampaigns cc ON cc.company_id = t1.selectedcompany_id  
INNER JOIN companies c ON c.company_id = t1.selectedcompany_id
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

I prefer using table alias to make queries more readable.

Comment: It throws syntax error: syntax to use near 'FROM customerselections ) WHERE customer_id='2' )

Comment: Sorry, had an extra close bracket. Fixed it. Can you try now?

Comment: Try fixing it. Should be something minor. I am too lazy to create DDLs and test.

Answer (score 0):

can you try below

SELECT * FROM

(SELECT * FROM customerselections  WHERE customer_id='$customerid')as  cs 
Inner join companycampaigns cc ON cc.company_id=cs.selectedcompany_id
INNER JOIN companies c ON c.company_id=cs.selectedcompany_id
LIMIT $offset,$limit

Comment: that gives syntax error. "syntax to use near 'FROM customer_id='14335')as cs INNER join companycampaigns cc ON cc.company_id' at line 2"

Comment: twice more slow than the OP's query.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

SELECT '$customerid',cc.*,c.logo
 FROM 
companycampaigns cc 
INNER JOIN companies c ON c.company_id=cc.company_id
where c.company_id in (SELECT selectedcompany_id FROM customerselections  FROM customer_id='$customerid')
LIMIT $offset,$limit

Comment: qshola: This query takes "seconds", deadly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like `` `customerselections`.`customer_id` `` is an `int`, but you are trying to do:

`WHERE customerselections.customer_id='$customerid'`

which would compare it to a string. Have you tried:

`WHERE customerselections.customer_id = $customerid`.

Comment: yes "customer_id" is INT. I have tried your suggestion. No luck.